# manipulate drop shadows in google maps on android platform

Tags: android, google-maps, transparency, dropshadow

I'm using the Google Maps api for Android, and when adding map markers, drop shadows are added automatically.

Now the problem I have is that one of the markers I use is black, and the drop shadow is also solid black, so that looks quite ugly as there is no distinction between the drop shadow and the actual marker any more.

Is there a way do do something about it? I like the drop shadows, and want to keep them. Most of the time they really add to the overall looks. Just in that case not. I'm hoping to find a way to either add a single-pixel white/grey line around the marker where the drop shadow touches the marker, or to make the drop shadow somewhat transparent instead of solid black.

To make matters worse (?) on my device (Android 2.2) the drop shadow's transparency is not constant but it varies while zooming. Sometimes it's quite transparent as it should be (and then it looks good), but most of the time it turns completely black.

Answer (score 1):

I would just disable the drop shadows and create your own as part of your marker image in Photoshop if you don't like how it renders. To do that, do this in your overlay subclass:

```
    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas, final MapView mapView, final boolean shadow) {
        // Don't draw the shadow layer
        if (!shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, you could use the same method to draw your own custom shadow layer if you want to muck about with the drawing APIs, but it's probably easier to just stick the shadow into your marker image beforehand.